# Mongoengine - "bad hint" error when using polymorphic models and hint()

Tags: mongodb, model, mongoengine, polymorphism, hint

According to the documentation, mongoengine should support also hint() with polymorphic models -- see:
http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html

The problem is that I can't find a way to use it, and there is no example in the documentation that refers specifically to the situation in which one has polymorphic models. 
For example if I have the following hierarchy:

```
class SFile(DynamicDocument):
    submission_id = StringField()

    meta = {                                            
            'allow_inheritance': True,
            'indexes' : [ {'fields' : ['submission_id']} ] # , 'cls' : False
            }


class TXTFile(SFile):
    name = StringField()

class ImageFile(SFile):
    vv = StringField()


# And create some documents:
sf = SFile()
sf.submission_id = '000'
sf.save()
```

I have displayed the indexes create:

```
indexes = SFile.objects._collection.index_information()
print [str(i) for i in indexes]
```

=> ['*id*', '_cls_1_submission_id_1']

So far so good. Now if I try to hint(), I get an error:

```
print SFile.objects(submission_id='000').hint([('submission_id', 1)])
```

=> Error: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: bad hint

According to the result of index_information(), the index name is _**cls_1_submission_id** - I think, but this throws the same error...

This works fine though if the model is not polymorphic...

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SFile.objects(submission_id='000').hint([('_cls', 1), ('submission_id', 1)])
```

Inheritable models add an extra field `_cls` to the index by default - you can turn this off by setting the `cls` field in the meta.  See http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=_cls#indexes

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar trouble and I think it's the `print [str(i) for i in indexes]` that's throwing you off. The dictionaries look like

```
'_id.course_instance_id_1__id.user_id_1__id.namespace_1': {
    'key': [('_id.course_instance_id', 1), ('_id.user_id', 1), ('_id.namespace', 1)],
    'v': 1,
    'background': False,
    'dropDups': False
},
```

and it's the `key` field you want to pass into `hint()` not the dictionary key, e.g.,

```
hint([('_id.course_instance_id', 1), ('_id.user_id', 1), ('_id.namespace', 1)])
```